# operator function in C++ and compile error relating to it

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

there are probably several ways I will expose my ignorance with this question :)

First, I think this is C++ code, but the extension of the file is .C (so maybe it is C?)

Anyway, I am trying to compile a program called Sundance (Sentence UNDerstanding ANd Concept Extraction) which is a Natural Language Processing tool. The compile error I get relates to the following:

```
// This class is used internally to keep track of constituents that are
// potential subjects for clauses during clause handling.
class PotentialXP {
public:
  Constituent* XPPtr;
  unsigned int Distance;
  unsigned int ClauseIndex;
  unsigned int ConstIndex;

  PotentialXP() {
    XPPtr         = 0;
    Distance      = 0;
    ClauseIndex   = 0;
    ConstIndex    = 0;
  };

  operator int() const {
    return (int)XPPtr;  
  };

  void Set(Constituent* w,
           unsigned int x,
           unsigned int y,
       unsigned int z){
    XPPtr         = w;
    Distance      = x;
    ClauseIndex   = y;
    ConstIndex    = z;
  };
};
```

The error is "cast from ‘Constituent* const*’ to ‘int’ loses precision"

and relates to the lines:

```
operator int() const {
  return (int)XPPtr;    
};
```

I understand why I get an error. XPPtr is of type Constituent*, so how can it be converted to an integer? Can anyone figure out what the author of the code wants to do here, and how I might rewrite this line so it compliles? What is an operator function (if that's what you call it) for?

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK C++ standard doesn't guarantee that pointer size will be the same as int size. So probably g++ just forces you to prevent problems. (Example: MSVC compiles 64-bit apps with 64-bit pointers but 32-bit 'int')

Comment: The key is figuring out why the original developer wanted an implicit cast to an integer. If I were looking at this I would probably comment out the operator and see what errors it threw up  in order to find locations where the cast was being used, and so what its purpose is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/eerSW) for me. You are on a 64-bit machine, where `size_t` is larger than `int`.

Explanation: you can historically convert a pointer an int

```
struct Foo {};

int main ()
{
    Foo * f = new Foo ();
    std :: cout << (int)f; // Prints 43252435 or whatever
}
```

If you want an integer which is the same size as a pointer, use `size_t` or `ssize_t`.

And why on earth are you writing `operator int()` like that anyway? Do you want `operator bool()` to test for validity? In which case a function body of `return NULL != XPPtr` would be better style -- clearer, at least.

Comment: Hi,

Yes, I'm on a 64-bit machine using Ubuntu and g++ to compile. Does this return 0 if the pointer is NULL and 1 otherwise? Is that the idea?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: See comments, test against NULL (or nullptr for C++11) explicitly. Conversion to int is allowed because of C compatibility, but you should prefer more specific types and explicit constants for readability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This isn't my code, so I'm trying to figure out what the author intends. I'm not sure if he/she intends to return 0 iff the pointer is NULL, or if something else is intended.

Comment: That's about the only reasonable interpretation. Pointers used to be synonymous with ints, but you haven't been able to rely on any particular integer value (except zero) for nearly thirty years. It's either a null test or an abusive practice.

Comment: Annoying, I don't have enough points to submit an answer, but here is what I've found:

As answerers have pointed out, the issue seems to be that I am using a 64-bit machine, and the pointer size is 64-bit whereas the integer size is 32-bit. I've rewritten the relevant lines as:

    operator long int() const {
      return (long int)XPPtr;    
    };

And I don't get a compile error now, so think the problem has been adequately dealt with. Many thanks to all respondents

Comment: That's not portable either, it should be `operator size_t()const;` or, better yet, `operator bool()const;`

Comment: For C the correct types would be `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` and not `size_t` etc. My strong suspicion is that for C++ this should be the same. These types are not guaranteed to exist on all platforms, though, but where they don't you probably just shouldn't try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The line `operator int() const` states a how your object can be cast to `int`.

The `Constituent*` can be cast to int because both types are usually the same size. I do not think that this is what the programmer intended, since the raw pointer value is of no semantic use. Maybe there should be a field lookup? E.g:

```
operator int() const {
  return (int)XPPtr->somevalue;    
};
```

Comment: I did wonder about whether that was intended (a field lookup), but I need to figure out which field

Comment: or, if XPPtr has it's own `operator int()`, then `{return (int)(*XPPtr);}` seems likely too.